# open org mode link in a different browser to the default browser

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way in the org mode syntax to create a link and to define which browser to open the link in? I have some links that I want to open in a different browser than my default one.

Comment: Do these links have some shared characteristics (other than that you want to open them with some other browser)?

Answer (score 5):

You can define a function that grabs the URL at point and calls one of `browse-url-<browser name>` functions. Taking the example of Chromium:

```el
(defun browse-url-at-point-chromium (&optional ARG)
  (interactive)
  (let ((url (browse-url-url-at-point)))
    (if url
    (browse-url-chromium url ARG)
      (error "No URL found"))))
```

And bind that function to a key:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-RET") 'browse-url-at-point-chromium)
```

This also works in other modes, such as `mu4e` (email in Emacs):

```el
(define-key mu4e-view-mode-map (kbd "C-RET") 'browse-url-at-point-chromium)
```

## macOS pitfalls

On macOS, the browsers with a Graphical User Interface (GUI) are not linked to shell executables, so Emacs can't see them in the default `browse-url-chromium` function, for example. So you need the additional step of giving Emacs the path to the executable:

```el
(setq browse-url-chromium-program "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium")
```

### macOS and Safari

If you want Safari on macOS, it has the additional problem that the executable does not take arguments (see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/689315/run-safari-from-terminal-with-given-url-address-without-open-command)). One solution from there is to call AppleScript to tell Safari to open the URL. The shell command is:

```bash
/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari & sleep 1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to open location "http://www.google.com"'
```

Another is to use `open -a Safari <URL>` in bash and `start-process` in ELisp:

```el
(defun browse-url-at-point-safari ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((url (browse-url-url-at-point)))
    (if url
            (start-process (concat "mozilla " url) nil "mozilla" url)
      (error "No URL found"))))
```

I was unable to make either of these work and found it easier to use another browser, such as Chromium.

Answer (score 2):

You can set which browser to use for all http(s) links with this:

```lisp
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-firefox)
```

You can also open different links with different browsers. As an example, the following setting opens links to Google docs with Chrome, and all other links with Firefox:

- Emacs >=28: `browse-url-handlers`.

```lisp
(setq browse-url-handlers
      '(("https://docs.google.com/\.*" . browse-url-chrome)
    ("." . browse-url-firefox)))
```

- Emacs < 28: `browse-url-browser-function`:

```lisp
(setq browse-url-browser-function
      '(("https://docs.google.com/\.*" . browse-url-chrome)
    ("." . browse-url-firefox)))
```

Answer (score 1):

More than two years later, and possibly not exactly what you were looking for, but still:

```
    M-x customize-option RET org-file-apps RET
```

Feel free to customise.

Comment: IIUC this specifies in general which app is used for which kind of link, whereas the OP wanted something specific to a particular link.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way that I use myself

1. Keep, e.g., eww as your default browser inside emacs `(setq browse-url-browser-function #'eww-browse-url)`
2. Click a formated link and when you're visiting a webpage in eww you can hit <kbd>&</kbd> (`eww-browse-with-external-browser`) to open the page in an external browser, e.g. firefox (your system default browser)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of other ways, than to brute force it;)

```
(defun extract-link ()
  (interactive)
  (when (org-in-regexp org-bracket-link-regexp 1)
    (let ((link (org-link-unescape (org-match-string-no-properties 1))))
      link)))

(defun open-org-link-in-firefox ()
  (interactive)
  (setq url (extract-link))
  (browse-url-firefox url)
  )
```