# Copy URL to the clipboard

Tags: mu4e

I can visit URLs in a message with `g`, bound to `mu4e-view-go-to-url`, which uses the default browser. How can I copy it to the clipboard to view it on another browser?

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use `k`, or `mu4e-view-save-url`, which saves it to the kill ring and to the clipboard.

## Looking for the `mu4e` function

For similar functions, it helps to look at the documentation and source code. Press `C-h k` and `g` to view the documentation for the function bound to `k`:

```
g runs the command mu4e-view-go-to-url (found in mu4e-view-mode-map), which is
an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘/usr/local/Cellar/mu/1.2.0/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e/mu4e-view.el’.

It is bound to g, <menu-bar> <headers> <goto-url>.

(mu4e-view-go-to-url &optional MULTI)

Offer to go to url(s). If MULTI (prefix-argument) is nil, go to
a single one, otherwise, offer to go to a range of urls.
```

Click the first link to visit the source code, which shows this function right after `mu4e-view-go-to-url`:

```lisp
(defun mu4e-view-save-url (&optional multi)
  "Offer to save urls(s) to the kill-ring. If
MULTI (prefix-argument) is nil, save a single one, otherwise, offer
to save a range of URLs."
...
```

Then from a `mu4e` buffer, you can find its key binding with `C-h f RET mu4e-view-save-url`:

```
mu4e-view-save-url is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘/usr/local/Cellar/mu/1.2.0/share/emacs/site-lisp/mu/mu4e/mu4e-view.el’.

It is bound to k, <menu-bar> <headers> <save-url>.

(mu4e-view-save-url &optional MULTI)

Offer to save urls(s) to the kill-ring. If
MULTI (prefix-argument) is nil, save a single one, otherwise, offer
to save a range of URLs.
```

## Defining a custom function

You can also define a function to open a link in a browser other than the default. The code is from [this thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26095/open-org-mode-link-in-a-different-browser-to-the-default-browser) and I was unable to make it work on Safari:

```lisp
;; set Chromium path on macOS
(setq browse-url-chromium-program "/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium")

;; code to follow links in different browser
(defun browse-url-at-point-chromium (&optional ARG)
  (interactive)
  (let ((url (get-text-property (point) 'shr-url)))
    (if url
    (browse-url-chromium url ARG)
      (let ((url (browse-url-url-at-point)))
    (browse-url-chromium url ARG)))))

(define-key mu4e-view-mode-map (kbd "J") 'browse-url-at-point-chromium)
```

Comment: This works for links/URLs in some emails, where the URLs are numbered `[1]` etc.  For other emails, there are URLs but no numbers.  I can move the point to the url with `TAB` and open it in the default browser with `ENTER` (or a mouse click), but there seems to be no way to copy the URL (other than `.` to see the source, do some searching, and select and copy the URL manually (sometimes into a scratch buffer as to remove some hard wrapping (often with `=` characters)).  In these emails, `g` and `k` give `[mu4e] No links for this message` in the buffer...  Is there a solution for such emails?

Comment: @AstroFloyd I'm sorry, I stopped using mu4e a few years ago. How about asking a separate question mentioning this thread?