# Copy mu4e link to clipboard

Tags: mu4e, clipboard

I would like to be able to copy a link from an mu4e email message to my system's clipboard.

There seem to be two types of links in mu4e messages:

1. messages where the URLs are numbered `[1]` etc.;
2. messages where links show up as underlined links.

For the first type, one can use `k` or `mu4e-view-save-url`, as described in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51140/17538).

My question concerns the second type.  For them, I can move the point to the link with `TAB` (in which case I can see the URL in the minibuffer), and open it in the default browser with `ENTER` (or a mouse click).  However, there seems to be no obvious way to copy the URL (other than `.` to see the source, do some searching, and select and copy the URL manually (sometimes into a scratch buffer as to remove some hard wrapping (often with = characters), or jumping to the `*Messages*` buffer and copying it there). In these emails, g and k give `[mu4e] No links for this message in the buffer`... Is there a solution for this type of emails?

(Often I *do* want to open the URL in a browser, but in a specific profile where I am e.g. logged in to a site.  Pressing `ENTER` will usually open the URL in a *different* browser profile, and then redirect me to the login page, so that the original URL is lost.)

Comment: And doing `0 w` says - at least for me - `No URL under point`, even when I see it when using `TAB`.

Comment: `shr-maybe-probe-and-copy-url` (u) for HTML mails does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [`c`](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/62f0a9a902031d172e03e8caaaad013a1798749f/mu4e/mu4e-view.el#L985) does that! It is by default bound to [`mu4e-copy-thing-at-point`](https://github.com/djcb/mu/blob/62f0a9a902031d172e03e8caaaad013a1798749f/mu4e/mu4e-helpers.el#L455-L465).
I've just found it out by mistake!

Comment: Haha, I like your mistakes - make more of them, and keep sharing them! ;-)