# Why can't I open a file in browser from Emacs on macOS?

Tags: osx, web-browser

I have emacs [installed with homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/emacs). I'm trying to open a file with:

```el
(condition-case ex
     (browse-url-default-browser (concat "file://" (buffer-file-name)))
  (error (message "Error: %s" ex)))
```

But all I get in the *Messages* buffer is:

`#<process open file:///[my-file-name].el>`

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What happens if you run `open file:///path/to/file.el` from the command line (with the appropriate path of course)? That's all that `browse-url-default-browser` does so if that does not work from the command line, there is no hope that it will work from emacs.

Comment: @NickD It opens the file in emacs if I run the `open` command from the terminal. I guess this is somehow a matter of permissions, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: It's probably more a matter of configuration than permissions: `.el` files are probably associated with Emacs, so `open` opens them in Emacs. Do `man open` as a first step and see how to configure it.

Comment: Alterantively, you can use `browse-url-chrome` to force the use of the specified browser. There are functions for `chrome`, `firefox`, `epiphany`, `kde`, `w3`, `chromium`, `conkeror`, `elinks`, `mozilla` - but not `safari` AFAICT, although you might find such an implementation if you serarch the web.

Comment: I think you are right it has something to do with `open`. I'll try to dig in further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer thanks on another one: [open org mode link in a different browser to the default browser](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26095/open-org-mode-link-in-a-different-browser-to-the-default-browser/47480#47480)

Apparently

> On macOS, the browsers with a Graphical User Interface (GUI) are not linked to shell executables, so Emacs can't see them in the default browse-url-chromium function, for example. So you need the additional step of giving Emacs the path to the executable:

Although Firefox is my default browser, I had to set the path to it but also use the appropriate function `browse-url-firefox` instead of `browse-url-default-browser`:

```el
(setq browse-url-firefox-program "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox")
(browse-url-firefox (concat "file://" (buffer-file-name))
```